# Flexbox expand full width an item from array of items

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I've got a piece of code doing what it is supposed to do when you run the code snippet. I want `filterbox` takes the whole width, and `flex-item` takes one third.

```css
.view-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.filterbox {
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-item {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="filterbox">FILTER</div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      Flex-ITEM
    </div>
 </div>
```

Now, I want to keep adding more `filterbox` and `flex-item` retrieved from an array `items`. My React code looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='view-content'>
            {this.items.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index} className='my-container'>
                        <div className='filterbox'>
                            <div>{item.filter}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex-item'}>
                            <div>{item.flex-item}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I had to wrap `filterbox` and `flex-item` in `my-container` and it breaks the flexbox code.
How would I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by it breaks your flexbox code ? When you add the items , You want the items to be displayed vertically ?

Comment: The parent container of `filterbox` and `flex-item` has to use `display:flex` like `.view-content` for flexbox to work. I had to wrap them in `my-container` because React JSX only allows to return 1 element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicate that the problem is caused by the fact, that React requires to return only one element, maybe you could wrap these elements in a [`<React.Fragment>`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) instead of a div. Please note that it requires React v16.2 or higher. This way your code would look as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className='view-content'>
            {this.items.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <div className='filterbox'>
                            <div>{item.filter}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='flex-item'}>
                            <div>{item.flex-item}</div>
                        </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This way it satisfies the requirement of having just one item returned in JSX, and in the final markup the fragment is not added as an actual DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, it 'breaks' your flexbox code because of the filterbox in the this.item.map

In your item, how do you make the difference between an item that should be a filterbox, and an item that should be a flex-item ?
Could you put here a visual example of what you try to achieve ?